# Plone: How to sort folder items

Tags: navigation, plone

I have a folder called `myfolder`, that has some items inside, like: `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, and etc.

When I added the portlet `Navigation` to the left column of the page, and entered on the folder `myfolder`, it showed me the links on the portlet like this:

- item1
- item2
- item3

I want that the `Navigation` portlet shows me links on this exact sort:

- item2
- item1
- item3

I know that I can go on the `Content` tab of myfolder`enter code here`, and drag each item to the position that I want.
But using this way, if I reinstall all my product on a new `Plone Site`, I lost my configuration. So I want to have this `navigation order` configured on my product, instead of only on a installed `plone site`, so that this change stays forever.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved: I could solve this by doing under the installation of the product:

```
#file: Extensions/Install.py
def install(portal):

    #...another steps from install

    portal = getToolByName(portal, 'portal_url')
    portal = portal.getPortalObject()

    portal.moveObjectsToTop(['item2', 'item1', 'item3', ])
    portal.plone_utils.reindexOnReorder(portal)
```

Just this.