# How to sort items in folder in Plone4?

Tags: sorting, plone

I hope to sort items in folder. I find a answer in [Plone: How to sort folder items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668539/plone-how-to-sort-folder-items).   But if there are many items in folder, it is hard to edit portal.moveObjectsToTop().

Any suggestion?

Best Regards.

Hugo

Comment: We need more detail to be able to help you. Do you want to just sort when displaying items, or do you want to re-order the items permanently? What sort order(s) do you need? If permanent, should the sort order be maintained automatically on mutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a Collection content
- Set it as the Default page of the folder
- Set Collection criteria to pick up items only in this particular folder
- In Collection you can choose between various fields for sorting (Title, dates, etc.) and between ascending and descending orders

Manual sorting is a feature used with folders where there are only few pages and sort order is desirable to reflect the natural story order of the site.